# find all files excluding one directory

Tags: bash, rm

so I want to clean a directory before I start work. I looks a bit like this.

```
./static
├── css
│   └── styles
├── img
│   └── pictures
└── js
    └── scripts
```

I want to `rm` the contents of `css` and `js` but not `img`.

I know I could just put both paths in but it bothers me so I tried this, with no success.

`rm -r ./static/{css,js}/*`

> rm: cannot remove './static/{css,js}/*': No such file or directory

Any ideas how I could make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"?  What shell are you using?  Why isn't `rm -r static/css/* static/js/*` good enough?  Also is it `static` or `.static` ?  Your two uses aren't consistent.

Comment: using bash like the tag and the title says, added a / to the tree. Why isn't it good enough? I didn't like to repeat myself, it actually is good enough but it bothered me.

Comment: Your command is correct for non-antique versions of bash. What is the output of `echo "$- $0 $BASH_VERSION"` and `ls -ld ./static/{css,js}` ?

Comment: Bash version is `himBH bash 4.3.42(1)-release` .  Using `ls`  as I did above presents the files I'd hoped to remove. Which to be honest just confused me more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is treated `*` as a file, try `rm -rf ./static/{css,js}/`

Alternatively,
Bash has **extended globbing** (first test, then remove the `echo`):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cd static
$ echo rm -rf !(img)
```

Or 
**Short Answer**

```
ls | grep -v "img" | xargs rm -rf
```

---

As suggested by OP in comment, Follow this step to do your job.
First dry run by printing the files to make sure you get what you are looking for.

```
$ find . -path ./img -prune -o -type f
./css/styles
./img
./js/scripts
```

After confirming, delete it.

```
$ find . -path ./img -prune -o -type f -exec rm {} \;

$ static/
  ├── css
  ├── img
  │   └── pictures
  └── js
```

Comment: cheers but I don't want to have to change directories, I really want to know about specifying or emitting specific directories in a tree.

Comment: @aaaaargZombies just use `rm -rf ./static/{css,js}/` without `*`

Comment: Also when testing this is wiping **everything**

Comment: @aaaaargZombies which command wiped everything ?

Comment: @aaaaargZombies and see my updated answer too, try that one

Comment: thanks @Rahul, your last comment was closest but didn't retain my folder structure. I'm a bit confused about why the {a,b} thing works in the case you suggested but not when specifying the files within it. Also to add more confusion the suggestion in the comment works when typed straight into the terminal but not in my NPM run script.

Comment: @aaaaargZombies which command wiped everything? The 'short answer'

Comment: What exactly you want to delete ? Delete all files from all sub directories excluding the one in `img` folder right?

Comment: Thats right @Rahul, the `scripts` and `styles` files in my description.

Comment: Do you want to preserver directory structure ? I mean directory should not be deleted just files should be, is that what you want ?

Comment: thats right....

Comment: @aaaaargZombies see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your persistence and correcting my terrible spelling in the title of my question!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit longer but I alway like `find` when I want to get specific. This should retain the structure and ignore the img dir.

```
find ./static -type d ! -name 'img' -exec rm -f {}/* \;
```

A breakdown of what's going on

`find` The command

`./static` specifying where to search

`type -d` Singling out directories

`! -name 'img'` Ignoring img dir

`-exec rm -f {}/* \:` The `{}`'s are replaced with the found dir names and the command is executed.